# Passing parameters between custom activities

Tags: .net, workflow-foundation-4

This is probably a very simple question, but I just can't figure out how to do it. I'm designing an application which uses MEF to load workflow activities. Those activities can be selected by the user. The selected activities should be executed in one workflow run. Each activity has the same input argument (list of items to work on).

I thought it would be best to create a sequence activity in code and add the selected activities in there. This "main sequence" can be started with the WorkflowInvoker. This works fine, but I can't figure out a way to pass the argument into the selected activities. I can pass it to the "main sequence", but I can't pass it from the sequence to the activities. Does anyone have an idea how to do this?

I must add a note, because the activities that are dynamically loaded are created with the visual studio designer (not Code/Native Activities).

Answer (score 0):

Create in code variables in root sequence and use them as InArguments in loaded activities

```
sequence.Activities.Add
(
  new MyActivity()
  {
    InArgument1 = new InArgument< int>(this.Variable1),
    OutArgument1 = new OutArgument< int>(this.Variable2)
  }
)
```

Comment: Problem is I don't have the actual type of the Activity, just know that it's an Activity. I could create a base Activity, problem is that I can't use this base Activity when I want to design is with the visual designer in visual studio.

Comment: >Those activities can be selected by the user.

You want to allow users edit workflow in rehosted designer or you have activity types selected by user? If you know type, you can create instance of this type and assign its properties